# while executing this sql statement in java i m getting this error

Tags: java, sql

this is my sql statement in java.

```
//validating for employee no exits in database or not

String importTable = getConfig().getImportTable();
        String sql = "update "
                + importTable
                + " set errMsg = case when errMsg is null or errMsg ='' then '' else errMsg + '<br>' end "
                + "+ 'Employeeno doesn't exists in the database.(' + employeeno + ')' "
                + " where employeeno is not null and not exists (select * from uae_empinfo where employee = "
                + importTable + ".cid)";
        executeCommand(sql);
```

this is the error:-

```
org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: StatementCallback; SQL []; Invalid SQL statement or JDBC escape, terminating ''' not found.; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Invalid SQL statement or JDBC escape, terminating ''' not found.
```

Comment: @no.good.at.coding: Oops!! I didn't notice. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that you have an embedded single quote here:

```
+ "+ 'Employeeno doesn't exists in the database.(' + employeeno + ')' "
// -------------------^
```

So you end up with unbalanced single quotes and invalid SQL. You need to properly escape your text before trying to turn it into SQL.

Comment: @vivek I fail to understand why you've not accepted this answer or any of the others in your previous questions. Are you unaware of how to do so? Please see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `PreparedStatement`, instead.